# UDP messages keep arriving even after the client is stopped or server restarted

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, buffer

I am sending UDP messages of 4 bytes size every 20 ms to the server. The client and the server are on the same machine.

I am experiencing a latency in receiving such huge amount of messages. 
After stopping and exiting from the client the server keeps receiving the messages.
I suppose that there must be some internal socket buffer that is filled.

The server is made in C++.
On the server side I am using and array of 10 buffers, 64bytes each
and am waiting to receive each UDP message here

```
static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 64;
static const int BUFFER_QUEUE_COUNT = 10;

int num = recvfrom(sSocket, buffer[bufferSelector], BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&senderAddr, &senderAddrSize);
```

I need to somehow stop receiving the messages after the client is closed.
If the server is restarted the messages are still arriving until some INTERNAL buffer is empty.

Now I have two questions ?

1. How to resize the internal buffer ?   or
2. How should I change the architecture of my server to increase the speed of receiving ?

My current architecture is based the following code:

```
while(true)
{
    if(server->State == Stopping) break;

    bool result = server->StartReceiving(*msg[msgIndex]);
    if( result == true  &&  server->State != Stopping)
    {
       server->numErrosCounter = 0;
       msg[msgIndex]->Tag = (void *)server;
       _beginthread(ActionThread, (unsigned int)0, msg[msgIndex]);
    }
    else if( result == false){
    }

...

}


bool UDPCommunicator::StartReceiving(Message &msg)
{
    State = Listening;
    PrintStateLn();

    sockaddr_in senderAddr;
    int senderAddrSize = sizeof(senderAddr);

    //int num = recvfrom(sSocket, buffer[bufferSelector], BUFFER_SIZE, NULL, NULL, NULL); // this works !!!
    int num = recvfrom(sSocket, buffer[bufferSelector], BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&senderAddr, &senderAddrSize);

...

}
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
If the client is sending each message with the delay less then 40 ms, for instance 35, 30, 25, 20 the problem of slow responsiveness is present. At speed of 40 ms there everything is fine.
So 40 ms means 25 fps, 20 ms means 50 fps.

Answer (score 0):

To modify socket buffer size you have to use `setsockopt()` function and change `SO_RCVBUF` and/or `SO_SNDBUF` option.